# Python: What happens if script stops while requests.get() is executing?

Tags: python, http, python-requests, python-requests-html

I know that `requests.get()` provides an HTTP interface so that the programmer can make various requests to a HTTP server.

That tells me that somewhere a port must be opened so that the request can happen.

Taking that into account, what would happen if the script is stopped (say, by a Key Board Interrupt, so the machine that is executing the script remains connected to the internet) before the request is answered/complete?

**Would the port/connection remain opened?**

**Does the port/connection close automatically?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short answer to the question is: requests will close a connection in the case of any exception, including `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit`.

A [little](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/sessions.py#L516) [digging](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/sessions.py#L596) into the requests source code reveals that `requests.get` ultimately calls the [`HTTPAdapter.send`](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/adapters.py#L393) method (which is where all the magic happens).

There are two ways in which a request might be made within the `send` method: chunked or not chunked. Which `send` we perform depends on the value of the `request.body` and the `Content-Length` header:

```
chunked = not (request.body is None or 'Content-Length' in request.headers)
```

In the case where the request body is `None` or the `Content-Length` is set, `requests` will [make use](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/adapters.py#L434) of the high-level [`urlopen`](http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.2.1/managers.html#urllib3.poolmanager.PoolManager.urlopen) method of `urllib3`:

```
if not chunked:
    resp = conn.urlopen(
        method=request.method,
        url=url,
        body=request.body,
        # ...
    )
```

The [`finally`](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/master/src/urllib3/connectionpool.py#L644) block of the `urllib3.PoolManager.urlopen` method has code that handles closing the connection in the case where the `try` block didn't execute successfully:

```
clean_exit = False
# ...
try:
    # ...
    # Everything went great!
    clean_exit = True
finally:
    if not clean_exit:
        # We hit some kind of exception, handled or otherwise. We need
        # to throw the connection away unless explicitly told not to.
        # Close the connection, set the variable to None, and make sure
        # we put the None back in the pool to avoid leaking it.
        conn = conn and conn.close()
        release_this_conn = True
```

In the case where the response can be chunked, requests goes a bit lower level and uses the underlying low level connection provided by `urllib3`. In this case, requests still handles the exception, it does this with a [`try` / `except`](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/adapters.py#L453) block that starts immediately after grabbing a connection, and finishes with:

```
low_conn = conn._get_conn(timeout=DEFAULT_POOL_TIMEOUT)

try:
    # ...
except:
    # If we hit any problems here, clean up the connection.
    # Then, reraise so that we can handle the actual exception.
    low_conn.close()
    raise
```

Interestingly the connection may *not* be closed if there are no errors, depending on how you have configured connection pooling for `urllib3`. In the case of a successful execution, the connection is put back into the connection pool (though I cannot find a `_put_conn` call in the `requests` source for the chunked `send`, which might be a bug in the chunked work-flow).

Answer (score 1):

On a much lower level, when a program exits, the OS kernel closes all file descriptors opened by that program.  These include network sockets.

Comment: Very interesting. Even more interesting is that, as the accepted answer says, the connection may not be closed if there are no errors... would be nice to explore that...